# What is the cause of this NPE?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tablayout

First, let's get things clear. NPE happens usually when a null element is being asigned a value. Funny enough, this is not what happens here, but I still get the NPE and I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong here.

I have a simple `tabLayout` in my `MainActivity`, which is not even hooked up with any fragments yet. I initialize and set it up like this:

```
ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabsLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Then I use a custom method to set the `View`s of each tab like this:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(initTabView(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_explore_black_18dp),
            getResources().getString(R.string.tab_map))), true);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(initTabView(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_perm_identity_black_18dp),
            getResources().getString(R.string.tab_profile))));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(initTabView(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baseline_loyalty_black_18dp),
            getResources().getString(R.string.tab_offers))));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(initTabView(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.qr_code_icon),
            getResources().getString(R.string.tab_scanner))));
```

And here is the method:

```
private View initTabView(Drawable tabIcon, String tabText) {
    View mainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    ImageView tabImageView = findViewById(R.id.tab_icon);
    TextView tabTextView = findViewById(R.id.tab_text);
    tabImageView.setImageDrawable(tabIcon);
    tabTextView.setText(tabText);
    return mainView;
}
```

I get the NPE on this line: `tabImageView.setImageDrawable(tabIcon);`, saying that its attempting to invoke the setImageDrawable method on a null object reference. How come the imageView is null, when I set it up two lines above? I am definitely missing something here, but don't know exactly what.

Comment: ```mainView.findViewById()``` will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come the imageView is null, when I set it up two lines above?

`findViewById()` returns null if the view was not found in the layout hierarchy.

You probably want to call `mainView.findViewById()` to search the just inflated view hierarchy instead of the activity view hierarchy.

Comment: But of course! I'm calling `findViewById()` without clarifying from which `View` it should get the id, so it gets it from the `MainActivity` view instead the `mainView`. Thank you!